# Connection timed out while trying to connect through Java Socket

Tags: 20.04, java, cloud

I have tried to connect to my ubuntu server from Google Cloud using Java's sockets. I runned my server and client both on `localhost`, and it worked. But when I ran it on the server, I couldn't create `new Socket(ip, port)` because of exception `java.net.ConnectException: Connection timed out: connect`. I'm working on port `18934` I have tried experimenting with iptables and firewall by using following commands:

```
sudo iptables -A INPUT -p tcp --dport 18934 -j ACCEPT
sudo ufw allow 18934
```

And also pinging server using `ping <ip>`, and it displayed that server is replying.

But from my Java code it didn't work and I'm getting same exception. It's probably due to my **ubuntu configured wrongly**, or some **google cloud settings** that I'm not aware of.
Thanks for any help.

Comment: To separate Java and Ubuntu problems, use `nc` instead. Also try running that command on the server (with the same IP, not localhost/127.0.0.1) to see if the server is listening properly on the right interface.

Comment: I have ran `nc <ip> 18934` and how do i know it is responding? I have seen on internet that i can type here to receive and send messages. Also when im running that command when my server socket running, it isn't giving me any response.

Comment: Try `nc -zv <ip> 18934`

Comment: And still nothing, same as previous command. Does it indicate that the port is not open?

Comment: Run it on the server too with the same IP. If blank, run with localhost. If nonblank, you need to set the listen interface. If blank, look for it in `ss -lt`. If still blank, the service is not started or listening on the wrong port

Comment: Running `nc -zv localhost 18934` on ubuntu worked, but `nc -zv <public ip> 18934` on ubuntu didn't work. I only got reply from my local computer by running `ping <public ip>` without any port.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have added port 18934 on google cloud VPC firewall and it worked. It was configured previously only to allow SSH connections from port `22`, i needed to set range `0.0.0.0/0`, and protocol/port `tcp:18934`.